# issue in creating a query for a scenerio

Tags: mysql, database

Good day!!

i am trying to achieve one objective which is i want to list down all the job that match the user criteria

my tables are like this

employer table has column

diploma
secondarySchool
BS 
masters
phd

similarly

candidate has same column as well

candidate table

diploma
secondarySchool
BS 
masters
phd

what i want to achieve is to list down all the employer where each employer column setting matches candidate.

for example

candidate has this setting

diploma = 1 , secondarySchool = 1 , BS = 1 , masters = 1, phd = 0

employer 1 has this criteria

diploma = 1 , secondarySchool = 1 , BS = 0 , masters = 0, phd = 0

employer 2 has this criteria

diploma = 1 , secondarySchool = 1 , BS = 1 , masters = 1, phd = 1

employer 3 has this criteria

diploma = 1 , secondarySchool = 0 , BS = 0 , masters = 0, phd = 0

in these examples employer 1 and employer 3 should list down as employer1 is looking for a guy who has diploma and secondarySchool. as candidate has equal and more than that and matching this criteria so this employer will be listed. employer 3 needs only diploma and which candidate has so this one will be listed too. where as employer 2 needs phd as well which candidate doesnt have so this employer wont be listed.

Firstly i though to use OR in mysql queries but it gives me all employers as it matches 1 or more it list down those employers

i tried to use union and union all as well which will take 2 ^ 8 as i have 8 columns in each table which doesnt look good to me.

it will be great if someone can guide me or let me know if i need to read some tutorial in order to achieve this.

Comment: It's not clear from the question whether employer and candidate have 1 column(each) or 4 columns(each) can you add your table definitions please as text (show create table <tablename> copy and paste)  and add sample data from both tables (select * from <tablename> copy and paste)  AND where is USER referred to here 'all the job that match the user criteria'

Comment: employer table has 5 columns  diploma, secondarySchool,BS, masters and phd and they can be set as 0 or 1 . 1 means employer need this education and 0 means it doesn't require this

 
candidate table has 5 columns  diploma, secondarySchool,BS, masters and phd and they can be set as 0 or 1 . 1 means candidate has this degree.

by user i mean candidate

Comment: I didn't downvote, but sometimes people will because they can and sometimes they will because they think it's not a good question, did you take the tour? and read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and sometimes they will because op does not answer request for clarification.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a simple thing to do just concat all the skills an requirements and compare them as integers (it does assume that you cannot have a phd without gaining a diploma,secondaryschool,bd,masters etc)

```
drop table if exists t,t1;
create table t
(diploma int,secondarySchool int, BS int , masters int, phd int);
create table t1
(id int, diploma int,secondarySchool int, BS int , masters int, phd int);
insert into t values
(1 ,  1 , 1 , 1, 0);
insert into t1 values
(1,1,1,0,0,0),
(2,1,1,1,1,1),
(3,1,0,0,0,0);

select t1.*,concat(t1.diploma,t1.secondaryschool,t1.bs,t1.masters,t1.phd) requirementlevel,
            concat(t.diploma,t.secondaryschool,t.bs,t.masters,t.phd) candidatelevel
from  t1
cross join  t 
where concat(t1.diploma,t1.secondaryschool,t1.bs,t1.masters,t1.phd) <=
            concat(t.diploma,t.secondaryschool,t.bs,t.masters,t.phd);

+------+---------+-----------------+------+---------+------+------------------+----------------+
| id   | diploma | secondarySchool | BS   | masters | phd  | requirementlevel | candidatelevel |
+------+---------+-----------------+------+---------+------+------------------+----------------+
|    1 |       1 |               1 |    0 |       0 |    0 | 11000            | 11110          |
|    3 |       1 |               0 |    0 |       0 |    0 | 10000            | 11110          |
+------+---------+-----------------+------+---------+------+------------------+----------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

BTW if you had published your sample data in a useable way I would have used that instead of making something up..